# Hiding internal work outputs by shell script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, script

I make a shell script that can update a tools. I want that when i run the

```
root@host:# sh script.sh
```

then the output will be

```
Its installing
Its done
```

But now my script look like

> root@host:# sh script.sh 
>   Its installing 
>  Showing internat script working outputs 
>  Its
>   done

As i know `stty -echo` command hide stdin in terminal and `stty echo` enable stdin show in terminal. But how can i hide the stander output by shell script ?

Comment: Unwanted output can be redirected to `/dev/null`, or to a file in case you need it for subsequent diagnostics.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/guides.html -> Two guides about bash-programming. These will answer all your questions.

Comment: @AFH. I try to redirect /dev/null but i failed.

Comment: check if you have at first line something like: #!/bin/bash -x and if yes remove -x

Comment: @Mastan - I think you need to give a little more information than "tried and failed": what did you try, and what was the nature of the failure?

Comment: @AFH. In my script there is a line. 
``mv /root/Desktop/lynis/plugins/* /etc/lynis/plugins/`` .
For that there is an output shows on terminal. I try the output redirect into **/dev/null** file but it doesn't work. I wrote the line 
``mv /root/Desktop/lynis/plugins/* /etc/lynis/plugins/ | &>/dev/null``.

Comment: You don't use the pipe symbol with redirection: your command should be `mv /root/Desktop/lynis/plugins/* /etc/lynis/plugins/ &>/dev/null`. The pipe symbol sends the output to another program's input; redirection sends the output to a file: you can't do both (although that the program to which output is piped can have its own output redirected, as in `prog1 | prog2 &> file3`).

Answer (score 1):

Redirect both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`:

`> /dev/null 2>&1`

OR in bash:

`&> /dev/null`

You can do it for all programs spawned by your script by using `exec` with the redirection at the beginning of your script.

`exec > /dev/null 2>&1`

Unless the programs you invoke in your script access the terminal directly (rare), this should cover you.

**One note on redirections:**
The order matters. It needs to be `> /dev/null 2>&1`, NOT `2>&1 >/dev/null`. I used to think the latter would work because `>` looks like an arrow which makes me think of pointers (as does the word "redirect"), and if I point stderr to stdout and then point stdout to /dev/null, then both should be pointing to /dev/null. That is not the case, though. File descriptors are not pointers and it is more helpful to think of `>` as sort of an assignment to a file descriptor rather than pointing. (Sort of, because technically, a fd is just a number and you need system functions like `dup2` to open a different file into the same file descriptor; but I think assignment is a good high-level abstraction).